# Do static transactional properties propagate to subclasses?

Tags: spring, grails

I have an abstract service class in grails that sets the transactional property.

Something like this:

```
abstract class AbstractService {

    static transactional = false
}

class MyService extends AbstractService {

    // methods
}
```

Are the methods in `MyService` also transactional false just by extending the `AbstractService`.

Answer (score 0):

In short yes but so long as you don't define

```
import grails.transaction.Transactional

import org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport


class TestingService extends TestService {
    //DO NOT ENABLE THIS OTHERWISE IT IS TRANSACTIONAL
    //static transactional = true
    def doIt() {
        def aa = TransactionAspectSupport?.currentTransactionInfo()
        return aa
    }

    @Transactional
    def doIt2() {
        def aa = TransactionAspectSupport?.currentTransactionInfo()
        return aa
    }


}
```

So if you overrider the static transactional then it becomes transactional. If you stick with static declaration in the extended abstract class, now even if you define @Transactional annotiation. The result will be null. For the tests below.

If transaction is not supported aa will return null, if it is you will see something like `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT`

Comment: I tried using `TransactionAspectSupport?.currentTransactionInfo()` to see if I was in a transaction but it just always returned null. Even inside a `withTransaction` block.